# Colorizing polygon layer with average within raster colour pixel

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, color

Further to the question [Assigning raster layer colors to polygons in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292052), I have used the expression proposed by @Babel solution with a positive result.

Is it possible to use a similar expression for the colour parameter with the **Field calc**, so that it works with a polygon layer and extracts the average colour value of all the pixels that are within each polygon?

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, have you tried Zonal Statistics, and what sort of result did that give you?

Comment: Sorry. I am relatively new to using QGIS and am unifamiliar with the capabilities of Zonal Statistics. I will investigate this option. I just tried the solution from @Babel which I found great because is no necessary to do any pre-process

Comment: Try Zonal Statistics, and then you can either answer your own question, or update the question with more detail. Keep in mind colours are just a mapping of the symbology - so an "average" colour might be a bit meaningless if you're randomly mapping individual colours. If on the other hand you have a graduated gray scale, then averaging should give you a pretty good outcome.